# Two recyclerview when i scroll down , the first recylcer to be scrolled too, how?

Tags: android

I want to have 2 grid images one vertical and second horizontal(recyclerview1 and recyclerview2), the first I want it to be always top and to be scrolled right and left, however when I scroll the second grid view , I want the first to be scrolled too as they are in  one scroller

example:

[image]

when I scroll down in the second recyclerview (recyclerview2) , i want the first recycler to be scrolled too. How to do that ?
result:

[image]

this is my code:

Main activity code:

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
       // initToolbars();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);
        recylerViewLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recylerViewLayoutManager);
        recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, subjects,images);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);


        MainGridRecView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.maingridrc);
        MainGridRecViewLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context,2);
        MainGridRecView.setLayoutManager(MainGridRecViewLayoutManager);
        MainGridRecViewAdapter = new MainGridRecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, subjects,images);
        MainGridRecView.setAdapter(MainGridRecViewAdapter);
```

activity xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/liner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/recyclerview1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#10bcc9"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="New Games." />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/recyclerview1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#10bcc9"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Used Games." />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/maingridrc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="330dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

  <!--  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />-->
</LinearLayout>
```

adapter

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Viewholder>{

    String[] SubjectValues;
    String[] imageValues;
    Context mContext;
    View view1;
    ViewHolder viewHolder1;
  // TextView textView;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context,String[] SubjectValues1, String[] images){

        SubjectValues = SubjectValues1;
        imageValues= images;
        mContext = context;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public ViewHolder(View v){

            super(v);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){

        view1 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_items,parent,false);

      //  viewHolder1 = new Viewholder(view1);

        Viewholder vh = new Viewholder(view1, new Viewholder.IMyViewHolderClicks() {
            public void onPotato(View caller) { Log.d("VEGETABLES", "Poh-tah-tos");
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,SingleObjectActivity.class);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            };
            public void onTomato(ImageView callerImage) {
                Log.d("VEGETABLES", "To-m8-tohs");

                //  v1    CategoryList mDataset = new CategoryList(getOrder(), getId(), item.getUrl(), item.getUserName(), item.getLikes());

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,SingleObjectActivity.class);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Viewholder holder, int position){

        holder.txtViewTitle.setText(SubjectValues[position]);
        holder.imgViewIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ghost_recon);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){

        return SubjectValues.length;
    }
}
```

recycler xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagecateg"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imagecateg"
        android:paddingLeft="35dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#f4e04c"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Looks like I missunderstood you. Could you please describe expected behaviour for the top recyler view? Should it always stay on the top, no matter how the second recyclerview is scrolled, or should it scroll out from the screen?

Comment: @YahorPaulavets when i scrolled the second recyclerview items , the top recycler view should be scrolled. as if the both recyclerview in one recylcer . understand me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to scroll entire layout when 2nd recycler view is being scrolled -> you can add your first recycler view as 1st item of the second recycler view, in this case they will behave like one recycler view.

I was able to implement a quick example, code is not brilliant, but it is reflecting general idea, [pushed to github](https://github.com/a-a-a-CBEI-I-IEE-M9ICO/recycler_view_example)

Here is the [main file](https://github.com/a-a-a-CBEI-I-IEE-M9ICO/recycler_view_example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/epavlovets/myapplication/RecyclerViewAdapter.java) with logic in the first RecyclerView adapter.

Comment: thanks for you answer , can you add an example or a link ?

Comment: can you show me an example or a link or anything please ?

Comment: @Moudiz implemented quick example, please try

Answer (score 0):

do some thing like this in your layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/horizenatlScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/verticalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

and here is java code.

```
    CustomAdapterHorizenatol horizontalAdapter = new 
    CustomAdapterHorizenatol(horizontalList);
    LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer
            = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 
    LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    horizontal_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer);
    horizontal_recycler_view.setAdapter(horizontalAdapter);


    CustomAdapterVertical vertical = new 
    CustomAdapterVertical(horizontalList);
    verticalScrollView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    verticalScrollView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    LinearLayoutManager verticallLayoutManagaer
            = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 
    LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    verticalScrollView.setLayoutManager(verticallLayoutManagaer);
    verticalScrollView.setAdapter(vertical);
```

Comment: when i added the property you mentioned , i am not able to scrol the second recylcer at all

Comment: Please set these properties to vertical recycle view before adapter set.

Comment: Please check i have prepared a code sample for you.
https://github.com/Maqsood007/-NestedRecycleView

Comment: i followed up your link but where i xan fins the code ? inside the app?

Comment: https://github.com/Maqsood007/-NestedRecycleView/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/kaimeramedia/githubentry/MainActivity.java